# How do I modify or remove system-defined shortcuts such as "app info" and "Pause app" in android

Tags: android, android-background, app-launcher, android-appshortcut, app-shortcut

[image]

I have tried retrieving all the existing shortcut using

```
shortcutManager.getShortcuts(ShortcutManager.FLAG_MATCH_PINNED) with all existing flag but it didnt retrieve "App info" and "Pause app" shortcut.
```

Comment: You can't modify or remove system-defined shortcuts such as "app info" and "Pause app" in Android. These shortcuts are part of the Android operating system and are not customizable by the user.

Comment: @Vinay I think it might be possible because I have seen some android app but those are google apps that doesnt show this options.